# How to handle different api for list and single element in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Hello guys.**

I have the following question.
Imagine that we have an application that represents a list of devices
and also user can go to the card of single device and see the whole information about it.

**Our api looks as follows:**

***For list:***

`[
    { name: 'Device 1', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Device 2', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Device 3', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Device 4', id: 4 }
 ]`

***For single device:***

`{
    name: 'Device 1',
    id: '1',
    elements: [{
        type: 'switch',
        name: 'socket'
    }, {
        type: 'multilevel',
        name: 'bulb'
    }],
    room: {
        name: 'living',
        id: 2
    }
 }`

As you see, api for list of devices is more lightweight. We dont want to make more database requests for list and also dont want force user to fetch unnecessary data for list.

And now, imagine that in device card user can edit 'name' of the device, for example.

How should I handle my state?
Should I store this state in two places?

Or should i handle my state tree in this way:
Application fetched list and every device object I mark as 'complete: false'

`{
    '1': {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Device 1',
        complete: false
    },
    '2': {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Device 2',
        complete: false
    }
}`

But, when user goes on the card, we fetch the whole device data, and then assign with our list object with 'complete' flag equals 'true'.
And the problem to handle state in both places disappears.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather not have duplicate data in the store because this leads to all of the usual problems (as you mentioned already). So my preferred model would be the second one, with a list or a map of all of your list entries. Whether you choose a list or a map depends on which requirements you have, e.g. fixed order, which cannot be easily achieved by a map.

I would not introduce a flag for completeness but instead let the object data determine this by itself. In your case, if `!entry.elements && !entry.room`, then the object is not yet complete and you need to fetch the additional data and add it to the object. I would not have the flag because the flag is redundant information which again can get out of sync.